# Lost connection to MySQL server at reading initial communication packet, system error: 111

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dns

I did PHP script to get data from sql database.

When I use *phpfiddle.org* (online php compiler), I can retrive data from table. But when I upload my php script to host server (*sql3.freemysqlhosting.net*), I am having this error

> lost connection to mysql server at 'reading initial communication
>   packet' system error 110.

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by any of the following reason:

- Check that MySQL is running
- Check the hostname you are using to connect
- Check the port you are using to connect the database

Answer (score 0):

I checked all. Everything working fine, when i host database and php from same hosting server (fdb3.your-hosting.net).

But when I put php in (your-hosting.net) and database in (sql3.freemysqlhosting.net), this error i am having again.